# Failed to initialize control interface /run/wpa_supplicant in journal but yet wlan works

Tags: networkmanager, wpa-supplicant

The wireless lan works, yet I have this log entries on `journalctl -b -p 3`. What is causing this?

```
Dec 11 21:26:09 raspberrypi wpa_supplicant[440]: Failed to initialize control interface '/run/wpa_supplicant'.
                                                 You may have another wpa_supplicant process already running or the file was
                                                 left by an unclean termination of wpa_supplicant in which case you will need
                                                 to manually remove this file before starting wpa_supplicant again.
Dec 11 21:26:09 raspberrypi NetworkManager[433]: <error> [1607718369.9284] sup-iface[0x2a0450,wlan0]: error adding interface: wpa_supplicant couldn't grab this interfac
```

`cat /etc/wpa_supplicant.conf`

```
ctrl_interface=DIR=/var/run/wpa_supplicant GROUP=netdev
update_config=1
country=US
network={
    ssid="foo"
    psk="bar"
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to stop the `NetworkManager` service which use `wpasupplicant`.

```
sudo systemctl stop NetworkManager
```

kill all `wpasupplicant` instances:

```
sudo killall wpasupplicant
```

or

```
sudo killall wpa_supplicant
```

To disable the `NetworkManager` service completely use:

```
sudo systemctl disable NetworkManager
```

Comment: Disabled it completely using `sudo systemctl stop NetworkManager`

Comment: I killed all `wpa_supplicant` processes, removed any configs related to wlan interface from `/etc/network/interfaces` or `/etc/network/interfaces.d` and then run `sudo systemctl restart NetworkManager` solved the issue.